# Push-уведомления

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-уведомления

У меня возник вопрос, вот есть приложения которые присылают уведомления типа `"Вы не заходили в приложение уже 2 дня`" и тому подобное. 
Эти приложения так же шлют нотификации через собственные сервера?

Нет возможности создавать локальные нотификации с таймером, что бы допустим через час после того как приложение закрылось, было показано уведомление?

Если нет, то получаеться мониторинг бездействия пользователя определяется так же по последнему конекту к серверу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете по последнему коннекту отсылать пуши, а можете запускать локальные нотификации. Например если пользователь свернул приложение, запускаем нотификацию,

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Notification"
    content.body = "Sample"
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false) //покажет через 5 секунд
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

если пользователь открыл приложение - убиваем ее.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [requestIdentifier])
}
```

Если не запускал определенное время - показывается.

Пример на [GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/NotificationExampleForSO)

Comment: А если интервал не 5 сек. поставить а 5 дней, и в течений этих 5 дней перезагрузить тел. то этот код уведомит?

Comment: @Murad интересный сценарий. Проверил на 5 минутах, после перезагрузки пришло уведомление.

Answer (score 0):

Удаленные push уведомления можно высылать со своих собственных серверов в любой момент времени. Тут два варианта

1. Напрямую отправить сообщение на APNS по адресу
   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
2. Воспользоваться сторонним сервисом, к примеру http://firebase.google.com Можно отсылать напрямую через консоль Firebase (Notifications->Новое сообщение), либо POST запрос на их сервер.

Вашу задачу можно реализовать обоими способами

Через удаленные уведомления - в приложении на бекенде постоянно сохраняете последнее время активности

Через локальные - с нужным интервалом пересоздаете единственное уведомление, которое сработает через нужный Вам период.

Оба уведомления сработают, если приложение закрыто.

Answer (score 0):

Такое обычно делается используя UILocalNotification. При каждом входе в приложение стираем уведомление и задаем новое на 2 дня.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2*24*60*60];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Вы не заходили в приложение уже 2 дня";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];}
```